# using gabor filter with cifar10 data then stacking the filtered images and feed the stacked image to a neural network

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to apply gabor filter on cifar10 data. As far as I understand, that should be done on two steps:
1 - using n gabor kernels to generate n gabor filtered images.
2 - Stacking the n gabor filtered images to get the original image back then feed it to my neural network.
I tried using

```
tfio.experimental.filter.gabor(
    input, freq, sigma=None, theta=0, nstds=3, offset=0, mode=None,
    constant_values=None, name=None
)
```

and here I have two questions:
1 - which argument in the tensorflow's function represents the kernel size?
2- After using this tensorflow's function, will I get back a stacked image or just filtered images that I should stack later using another function.

Comment: Do you assume that sigma is the standard deviation, theta the orientation, psi the phase offset, lambda the wavelength (or frequency) and gamma the spatial aspect ratio? If that's the case, the parameters of the function should be self explanatory.

Comment: I do not have specific assumptions. I read tensorflow documentation and I could not match the arguments with gabor function parameters. Your answer is taking a question form, should I consider it as solution to my question or you are just suggesting this match?

Comment: I was asking for you to precise your question. What do those greek letters represent to you?

Comment: Thanks, I see your point. Do you have any suggestions for the second question?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the following for the parameters:

- lambda is the wavelength of the sinusoidal factor,
- theta is the orientation of the normal to the parallel stripes of a Gabor function,
- psi is the phase offset,
- sigma is the sigma/standard deviation of the Gaussian envelope and
- gamma is the spatial aspect ratio

Then, this is equivalent to calling the TensorFlow/IO function with the following parameters:

```
tfio.experimental.filter.gabor(input, 
    freq=(1/lambda), 
    sigma=(sigma, sigma/gamma), 
    theta=theta, 
    nstds=3, 
    offset=psi, 
    mode=None, 
    constant_values=None, 
    name=None)
```

The kernel size is defined by the `nstds` argument.

The output of the function is the resulting images already stacked. To convince ourself, we can [look at the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/io/blob/v0.17.0/tensorflow_io/core/python/experimental/filter_ops.py#L143-L245):

```
real = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(
    input, tf.cast(tf.math.real(g), input.dtype), [1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID"
)
imag = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(
    input, tf.cast(tf.math.imag(g), input.dtype), [1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID"
)
```

The input in convolved with the gabor kernel with a depthwise convolution, that concatenates the output together, as specified in the [documentation of the function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/depthwise_conv2d) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Given a 4D input tensor ('NHWC' or 'NCHW' data formats) and a filter tensor of shape [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, channel_multiplier] containing in_channels convolutional filters of depth 1, depthwise_conv2d applies a different filter to each input channel (expanding from 1 channel to channel_multiplier channels for each), **then concatenates the results together.** The output has in_channels * channel_multiplier channels.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why are you making freq = lambda? I thought freq should equal the reciprocal of lambda and unfortunately the documentation of gabor filter function does not show the link between the argument 'freq' in the function and the wavelength. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: `freq` is supposed to be `1/lambda`, it's a typo on my side.